# plugin not defined in gazebo?

Tags: plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello every today when i try to work with my SDF model in gazebo , i find my plugin could't use any more , does any one see this before ?

```
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[plugin], child of element[joint] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[joint]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <joint>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <model>
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error [parser_urdf.cc:2691] Unable to load file[/home/tiange/.gazebo/models/my_robot/model.sdf].
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200770/plugin-not-defined-in-gazebo-?/) by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2015-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pure Gazebo question should better be asked on http://answers.gazebosim.org

Ref. http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2012-September/052142.html

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-12**:
oh i see , thank you~